# problem with video player

Tags: 14.04

i have recently installed ubuntu 14.04. when i  try to play video that is not working it says Videos requires to install plugins to play files of the following types:
• MPEG-4 AAC decoder
• H.264 decoder
 but software is updated.

Comment: Did you already install the ubuntu--restricted-extras metapackage? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment: no when i try to install that says unable locate package

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that some video (an music) codecs are propriety and owned by there respective parties, this means you must install them after installing Ubuntu.

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Now your videos will play.

Comment: when i type above code it come look like       ,Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: Are you on |Ubuntu unity ? or something else like K or X ubuntu ?

Comment: i dont know then how can i check that

Comment: @ArulrajFigurado You must enable the multiverse repository; you can do this in Software & Updates

Comment: Does your desktop look like this http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-GqveVKiyJPg/U0-cPr1DqUI/AAAAAAAASRo/qe6alekGyIA/s1600/ubuntu14.04-unity.png

Comment: yes. something like this

Comment: OK Click the icon in the top left (dashhome) and search for `software and updates` and click it, make sure all these boxes are checked (except `source code` which has a -) With all four boxes checked run the command again

Comment: the same problem comes again.

Comment: Strange, go here https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/, click the software center link, open it, what does it say ?

Comment: it ask to use multiverse source

Comment: Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras `